# CAMetalLayer nextDrawable Called Early

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

[image]

when provisioning I am seeing this Issue. What is the reason behind this one.

Comment: Did you read here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cametallayer/1478172-nextdrawable

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any solution, or anymore details you could give us?